# How to prevent a runtime crash when passing NULL to std::wstring?

Tags: c++, string

I have a function like this:

```
void Test(std::wstring test1)
{
   cout << test1.c_str();
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
Test(NULL);
```

I get runtime exceptions like "invalid handle" and the entire program crashes. I can't do a null check on parameter 'test1' because the compiler says it can't be null. I'd like to either prevent a NULL from being passed in the first place, or have a way to check for NULLs at runtime. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Compile your code with proper flags, I think it should work with a warning. **No** ?

Comment: Why are you passing `NULL` to a function that's not expecting a pointer?

Comment: is the parameter being passed a wchar_t*?

Comment: Ummm... don't pass `NULL`?

Comment: I don't have control over what programs are passing the data, and sometimes people use a NULL. We used to use LPWSTR and it took a NULL parameter just fine, but now that we're moving to std::wstring anywhere with a NULL just explodes the program. :(

Comment: What did the program do before when passed a null pointer? No-op? Can you just remove those calls?

Comment: @JonTackabury, If you're moving to `std::wstring`, it should fix itself when you change the callsites to use `std::wstring`. If those are in user's programs, then an overload would probably be the best solution for them not to change their code, but you can at least change the code you manage to call it correctly.

Comment: @JonTackabury Changing the parameter type from `LPWSTR` to `std::wstring` changes the interface, as you've discovered. You either have to update the client code to adhere to the new interface or you have to do something to maintain the old interface (e.g., by adding an overload that works with NULL).

Comment: @bames53: It's true, I was hoping std:wstring would be a drop-in replacement, but it turns out it's not so easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you expect `Test(NULL)` to do?  I think you may be confusing a null pointer with an empty string.  They are not the same thing though some other strings classes might treat a null pointer as a special case and construct and empty string.  You probably just want `Test(L"")`;

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately in this case you just have to write correct code: The null pointer is implicitly convertable to `wstring` (through the C-string constructor) and that constructor requires the C-string pointer to be non-null.

You have to do the null check *prior* to calling `Test`. You *could* implement an overload to help with this though:

```
void Test(const wchar_t* test1)
{
    if(test1) Test(std::wstring(test1));
}
```

Note that this may hide problems and you may want to assert in the overloaded `Test` function and/or simply fix the calling code so it never passes in an invalid string in the first place.

Comment: Doing a null check before calling the function, or creating overloads seems like the best (and only) real options. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Damn, it's always unfortunate when one has to write correct code :D

Answer (score 1):

The specification for `std::wstring` says that you must not pass `NULL` to `wstring`'s constructor. Doing so results in undefined behavior.

To avoid this you can overload your `Test` function such that passing `NULL` calls an overload that doesn't try to construct `wstring` from `NULL`.

```
void Test(wchar_t const *test1)
{
   if (test1)
     std::wcout << test1;
}

void Test(std::wstring const &test1) // added const & to avoid unnecessary copies
{
   Test(test1.data());
}
```

Now `Test(NULL)` will call the `wchar_t const *` overload and `NULL` will never be passed to the `std::wstring` constructor.

Comment: I'll give you that you can overload it for the easiest solution to integrate with the existing code, but you can output the string directly, and should use `std::wcout` to do that.

Comment: @chris well one should avoid duplicate implementations. Although I show implementing the new overload in terms of the OP's code I grant that it would probably be better to refactor and flip that around.

Comment: I already UVed :) This was the first to suggest overloading, and the output wasn't relevant to the actual answer, so it didn't influence my decision.